# How to update ThreadPoolExecutor threadpool size at runtime

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have following code where I have 3 classes

1. ThreadPoolTest.java
2. Parent.java(Runnable)
3. Child.java(Runnable)

I have scheduled parent thread after every 10 seconds from ThreadPoolTest.java, once a parent thread is launched, in its run() it creates 100 child threads.

My requirement is that every-time parent thread is launched, I want to use same thread executer.

Currently I have given the pool size of 50.
At run-time I want to update this pool-size for every parent thread execution.

Can this be achieved?(is it advised?)

If yes, how can we achieve this?

```
public class ThreadPoolTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        Thread parentThread = new Thread(parent);
        parentThread.setName("Parent");
        try {
            ScheduledExecutorService executor_instant = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            executor_instant.scheduleAtFixedRate(parentThread, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


public class Parent implements Runnable {

private static ThreadPoolExecutor executor;
private static int threadPoolSize = 50;
static {
    executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);

}
@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Child child = new Child();
        executor.execute(child);
    }
}
}


public class Child implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Hi this don't do what you need ? [setMaximumPoolSize(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setMaximumPoolSize(int))

Comment: You can use [`Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool--) instead.

Comment: I created executor in run method and after for loop I used executor.shutdown(), so now I can pass pool size for every creation, which is what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Use `setCorePoolSize(int)` to set the new min size.

I suggest you use `Executors.newCachedThreadPool`, that way, you give the responsbility of creating the thread pool size to `ThreadPoolExecutor`.`ThreadPoolExecutor` creates new threads if needed to execute the new tasks, and reuses the existing ones with `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`

Comment: I created executor in run method and after for loop I used executor.shutdown(), so now I can pass pool size for every creation, which is what I needed.